# notBlank constraint not working for File input - Form with OneToMany relationship Symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a OneToMany relationship between `Article` and `Image` entities. I created the Article's form like:

```
class ArticleType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder

            ->add('articleTitle','text',array('required' => false))
            ->add('articlePrice','number',array('required' => false))
            ->add('images', new ImageType())

        ;

    }
....
}
```

And

```
class ImageType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('file', 'file',array('required' => false))

        ;
    }
....
}
```

I have a problem in validating the file attribute. My goal is to return an error message when user chooses no file (at least one image should be associated to an Article). I tried by asserting the `NotBlank` but it doesn't work.

```
<?php
....

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;


class Image
{


 /**
     * Image file
     *
     * @var File
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $file;


   ....
}
```

I don't [embed collections](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) while creating my form, since project requirements oblige AJAX uploading for each image separately before submission of the whole form. In other words, a javascript event listener, bound to input `change`event, creates the AJAX call which uploads the image after validation (ie. file is validated for size, extension, in controller). But when I send the overall form, only the other fields are validated and form is submitted even if no file is choosed (I see in headers all formData elements except the file one).

I want to notice that the form is rendered correcly when I inspect element in browser.

I spent a lot of time trying to resolve this issues but to no avail, your help is a rescue.

**Edit:** As requested by Mr Nawfal Serrar

The AJAX call is performed like:

```
$(':file').change(function(){

        var file = this.files[0];

        var url= $('.article-form').attr('data-iu-url');

        var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            success: completeHandler,
            data: formData,
        });

    });
```

`url` contains the route `image_upload` respecting following config:

```
image_upload:
    pattern:  /{id}/image_upload
    defaults: { _controller: ShopManagementBundle:Image:uploads}
    requirements: { _method: post|put }
```

Controller:

```
   public function uploadsAction(Request $request, $id) {

            if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
                $image = $request->files->get('articletype')['images']['file'];

                $status='success';
                $message='';
                $uploadedURL='';
                $the_id=0;


                if (($image instanceof UploadedFile) && ($image->getError() == 0)) {

                    if ($image->getSize() < 50000000000) {
                        $originalName = $image->getClientOriginalName();
                        $name_array = explode('.', $originalName);
                        $extension = $name_array[sizeof($name_array) - 1];
                        $valid_file_types = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'bmp', 'png', 'gif');
                        if (in_array(strtolower($extension), $valid_file_types)) {

                             $imagee= new Image();

                             $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                             $imagee->setFile($image);

                             $imagee->setSubDir('hg');
                             $imagee->upload();

                             $entity = $em->getRepository('ShopManagementBundle:Article')->find($id);
                             $imagee->setAricle($entity);

                             $uploadedURL= $imagee->getUploadDir(). DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $imagee->getSubDir(). DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $image->getBasename();


                            $em->persist($entity);
                            $em->persist($imagee);
                            $em->flush();
                            $the_id=$imagee->getId();

                        } else {
                            $status = "fail";
                            $message = "extension problem";
                        }
                    } else {
                        $status = "fail";
                        $message = "Image size too big";
                    }
                } else {
                    $status = "fail";
                    $message = "Error uploading";
                }

                return $this->render('ShopManagementBundle:Image:image_portion.html.twig', array(
                    'status'      => $status,
                    'message' => $message,
                    'uploadedURL' => $uploadedURL,
                    'image_id'=>$the_id,

                   ));
            }
            else
                return new Response('RE try uploading');
        }
```

As you can see I am not validation using `isValid` in controller, I validate with if-else statements assuming that the file is already sent.

Comment: Did you try `@Assert\NotNull` ?

Comment: @GrégoryElhaimer, I tried it but in vain. In fact, all Assert declarations (Size, MimeType...) don't work. Since I perform seperate AJAX upload for each image, I validate all constraints in controller each time, but the remaining problem is how to validate minimum number of upload file in the whole `Article` form. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Then you'de better make an embedded collection of images and add constraints on it. Would be the simpliest way to do.

Comment: @GrégoryElhaimer, well honnestly I already tried it but something was wrong (maybe the fact that an Image entity is persisted, before the whole form is submitted, is the cause ). I will retry it and feedback here.

Comment: @GrégoryElhaimer, Additionnaly,I think that embedded collection will require the use of  an Array or ArrayCollection for the set of Images, which will lead to Images persistence(files upload) at the same time and at the Article form submission (all the files at the end).I need to upload images separately in time(whenever an input change event occurs, upload instantly the file with AJAX).After all uploads finished, the global Article form is submitted,but what if a user uploads no image?requirement is 1 as min number of image. Please to correct me if I am wrong,your experience is invaluable.

Comment: Are you telling me that you persist several Images for one Post ? Then it MUST be a ArrayCollection. Moreover, how to you link images with the post which is not created yet ? In any case, you'll have to make a constraint on `$images` property within Post and link the uploaded images to this post. You must find a way to bind them afterwards.

Comment: @GrégoryElhaimer, Exactly. I persist several Images for  one `Article` (onetomany). Thank you for the second question because it  smartly points  the issue. In fact, I persist an empty Article entity to which I join Images (using article_id as join value in database) , then when the whole form is submitted I edit that same instance of Article. That's the solution I ended up using due to AJAX requirement

Comment: @GrégoryElhaimer could you please look at my edit, I added controller code which explains more how Image persistence comes after Article persistence (I pass article id as parameter to upload action)

Comment: @GrégoryElhaimer, I tried constraint on images within Article as you suggested(with bothe notBlank and notNull), but to no avail. I see in HTTP headers that formData doesn't contain part for `images`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73255/discussion-between-gregory-elhaimer-and-whiteletters-and-blankspaces).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After all we said in comment zone, I would recommand you to use `@Assert\File` for your file upload validation. It will prevent your if/else stack.

Since you told me you were attaching the uploaded files to an already existing Article, then using an embedded collection of forms would be the solution as I mentionned.

Since you'll retrieve the article and then create a form type with it, all the Images will be linked to it.

Add the [count constraint](http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/reference/constraints/Count.html) on the Images list of your:

```
/**
 * @Assert\Count(
 *      min = "1",
 *      minMessage = "You must upload at least one image",
 * )
 */
private $images;
```

Since you will retrieve the Article which is already linked to uploaded Image instances, the validation will not throw an error. Otherwise, the user is trying to submit the form without images. The validation constraint will then make the form invalid.

There might be other little stuff to do to make it work, but it should help you to go ahead.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, I believe now that embedded collection (which is the standard way of doing oneToMany) is the solution. I will be implementing your answer and come to feedback

Comment: Was it the solution ? Still waiting for your feedbacks :)

Comment: I didn't work from that day :D. It is the solution of course , just I need time to know what are other stuff to mention as edit to your answer. thank you

Comment: I am forced to use validator service instead of isValid function since the latter requires submitting the form, while I am using javascript change event on file input and AJAX to upload image. Please to correct me if I am wrong and thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Think about using 2 forms : one for upload (with the choose file input) and one which embedded the instances of Image. Each time you post a file, you check the server response and then add a new "row" into the Article form.

Comment: I really need time to compare your approach with mine (I don't even master mine and feel that yours will require a bunch of changes). Additionnaly, requirement is to upload image directly after file input `change` event and maybe your approach is requiring a `submit` button. Anyways, I see that the validator service is working well and using my Asserts. Thank you. Can I come back here if I have other ideas to discuss?

Comment: There is nothing complicated, I'll try to make a scheme if I got time :)

Answer (score 1):

To properly handle file uploads better to follow this method :

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html

Its the official one, then at the return of the upload method you check if there is no file return your error message else continue with your upload.

Comment: Link to the official doc : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html ;)

Comment: @NawfalSerrar  In my situation the `upload` method is executed before the whole form is submitted. It is due to AJAX. So whenever the file input receives a file, `upload` is called. What if a user uploads no image for an Article and submitted  the form? I need validation on the number of files attached. I hope I was clear this time. many thanks. N.B: Official doc was the starting point of this task.

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces can you edit your question with how do you handle image with the ajax and how you get data in your controller action.